# Determinants and diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, diagonalization

Does the determinant of a matrix affect if it is diagonalizable or not?

Like, if $\det(A) = 0$ does that mean the matrix is NOT diagonalizable?

Comment: What's the determinant of a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Here is an example of a 2 X 2 matrix with zero determinant that can be diagonalized: A = {{4 -2}{-2 1}} The 'diagonalizer' is {{1 -2}{2 1}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and the zero matrix is an obvious example in which $\det(A) = 0$ and is itself diagonal. Also note that any diagonal matrix with at least one zero entry on the diagonal has determinant 0.

Answer (score 4):

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. $\det A = 0$, $A$ is diagonal.

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. $\det B = 0$, $B$ is not diagonalizable.

$C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. $\det C = 1$, $C$ is diagonal.

$D = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. $\det D = 1$, $D$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @Amzoti: I meant $\det D = 1$, thanks for catching that (did I miss something else?). It was a rough shot at showing that the two things are independent in some sense.